# how could I make sure the index is the smallest in union-find algorithm?

Tags: c++, union-find

I have a N*N boolean symmetric matrix to show the relationship of each element.

for example matrix

```
1 0 1 
0 1 1
1 1 1
```

means element 1 has relationship with 1, 3; element 2 has relationship with 2,3, etc.

Now I want to cluster the elements, as the matrix size is large (N=9000), I don't want to use three layer for loop, and want to use union-find algorithm instead.

```
int labels[N];

static int find(int u){
    return u == labels[u] ? u : labels[u] = find(labels[u]);
}

static void myunion(int u,int v){
    labels[find(v)] = find(u); // the value of v is always larger than u
}
```

For the execution code:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for{int j=i+1;j<size;j++){
        if(matrix[i][j]==1){
            myunion(i,j);// the value of j is always larger than i
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want to always use the smallest index as the cluster label, but sometimes my code doesn't use the right label.

For example, element 2, 3, 100 are related. I want the cluster has the label 2, but I got the result of label 100. Could anyone tell me my logic error?

I am not sure whether

```
int pv = find(v);
int pu = find(u);

if(labels[pv]>=labels[pu]){
    labels[pv] = labels[pu];
}
else{
    labels[pu] = labels[pv];
}
```

works, because I'm afraid if, for example, {1,2,3}->label 1  ;{4,6}->label 4  when I call union(3,4), will labels[6] also be modified to 1?

Comment: Just to understand better, for the given in the post `3x3` matrix. Am I correct that the desired result is `element 1,3 -> label 1`, `element 2 -> label 2`, `element [none] -> label 3`?

Comment: @PetrBudnik Actually, from my example, as element 1 and 3 are related, and element 2 and 3 are related ,element 1,2,3 belong to the same cluster, whose label should be 1 (the smallest index).